# How to apply a function that returns a promise to each list item in Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, promise, google-cloud-firestore, ramda.js

I have a list of names and each needs to do a database fetch from Firebase. The FireStore get function returns a promise.

How do I work that in to Ramda? I've tried ComposeP/pipeP but I need these to work in a loop.

Think I'm missing something obvious as I'm just getting in to functional programming.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds as though you simply want `Promise.all`.  Do you want to do something Ramda-ish with the results?

Answer (score 4):

It's not quite clear to me what you're looking for, but at first glance I believe you simply need `Promise.all`.  Here is a simple solution that mocks Firebase and composes `Promise.all` with the Firebase call.  After a 1 second delay, it should log the correct values.

```js
const people = {
    barney: {name: 'Barney Rubble', id: 1}, 
    betty: {name: 'Betty Rubble', id: 2}, 
    fred: {name: 'Fred Flintstone', id: 3},
    wilma: {name: 'Wilma Flintstone', id: 4}
}

const FakeFirestore = {
  get: name => new Promise(r => setTimeout(_ => r(people[name]), 1000))
}


const getAll = R.compose(Promise.all.bind(Promise), R.map(FakeFirestore.get))

getAll(['betty', 'wilma']).then(R.map(console.log))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

But note that the Ramda calls are not particularly important here.  `getAll` could just as well be written as `const getAll = names => Promise.all(names.map(FakeFirestore.get))`.

Comment: You understood it perfectly. That's just what I was looking for thanks!